# Sign in anonymously with Firebase by using Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to implement a method to anonymously login users in Unity by using Firebase. I want to do so by calling a Cloud Function:

```
   exports.registerUserAnonymously = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
      try {
        const userRecord = await admin.auth().createUser({anonymous: true});
        return await createUserDocument(userRecord, null);
      } catch (error) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError("register user anonymously error", error.message, error);
      }
    });
```

As intented, it generates a user in my Firebase project, BUT in Unity the variable auth.CurrentUser is never set (== null).

Here is the method I use in Unity for signing-in the user:

```
public async void SignInAnonymous(){

    QuickLoadingManager.EnableLoadingPanel();

    var function = FirebaseFunctions.DefaultInstance.GetHttpsCallable("registerUserAnonymously");

    await function.CallAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
    {
        if (task.Exception != null)
        {
            Debug.Log(task.Exception.GetBaseException().Message);
            OnFailedSignUp(task.Exception.GetBaseException().Message);
        } else if (task.IsCompleted)
        {
            Debug.LogError("SignInAnonymouslyAsync succ");
            OnSuccessfulSignIn();
        }
    });

}
```

Again, my problem is that by calling the Cloud Function, the CurrentUser it not set, and I am also not allowed to assign the CurrentUser myself, since it is readOnly. As Alternative I could always to the sign-in in Unity instead of calling a Cloud Function, but I would prefer the Cloud Function approach. Is there any way to implement that logic with Cloud Functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signing in a user in Firebase Authentication requires that the client-side code gets and stores an ID token for that user, which you code doesn't do. If you really want to implement this, follow along with the documentation on [implementing custom authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/custom-auth) (for the code on the client) and [creating custom tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) (for the code on the server).

This process is quite involved though, so unless you have a specific requirement and time to learn the setup I linked above, I'd usually recommend to [use the client-side anonymous authentication provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/anonymous-auth) that is built into Firebase.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i ended up using the built in client side approach